# How can I use DispatchGroup to look up photos and store in UIImage array

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, dispatch-queue

I have looked at quite a few examples of using dispatch group but I can't seem to get it to work.

I am using Google Maps for my project, and have placed markers at nearby businesses. When a marker is clicked, I want to show another view controller which has images of the place.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
  self.loadPhotosForSalonByPlaceId(placeID: poiItem.placeId)
  photoDispatchGroup.wait()
  let salonInfoViewController = self.addPullUpController() //show view controller


  salonInfoViewController.ImageCarouselView.images = self.salonImages
  salonInfoViewController.salonName.text = poiItem.name
  salonInfoViewController.salonAddress.text = poiItem.address
  salonInfoViewController.openAppointmentSlotArray = self.openAppointmentSlots

  self.isSalonInfoViewPresented = true
  return isSalonInfoViewPresented
}
```

This is what my loadPhotosForSalonByPlaceId looks like:

```
func loadPhotosForSalonByPlaceId(placeID: String){

    var countToLimitToFiveImages = 0
    GMSPlacesClient.shared().lookUpPhotos(forPlaceID: placeID) { (photos, error) -> Void in

        if let error = error {
            // TODO: handle the error.
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            for photoMetadata in (photos?.results)! {
                if countToLimitToFiveImages == 5 {
                    break;
                }
                self.photoDispatchGroup.enter()
                self.loadImageForMetadata(photoMetadata: photoMetadata)
                self.photoDispatchGroup.leave()
                countToLimitToFiveImages += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I using the enter and leave incorrectly? Or should I be notifying the main thread to continue after the lookUpPhotos completes? Because right now, the array of UIImages is empty by the time I want to show the view controller.

Thanks in advance!

The code below is what I call in my loadPhotosForSalonByPlaceId function. It converts the PhotoMetaData into a UIImage, which I append to my array. From what I understand, the look up photos and the loadplacephoto are async calls. How can I go use DispatchGroup to show my view controller after both of these tasks are finished.

```
func loadImageForMetadata(photoMetadata: GMSPlacePhotoMetadata) {
    var image = UIImage()
    GMSPlacesClient.shared().loadPlacePhoto(photoMetadata, callback: {
        (photo, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            // TODO: handle the error.
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")

        } else {
            image = photo!
            self.salonImages.append(image)

        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of DispatchGroup currently is all wrong. You should call `enter` before an async process starts and you call `leave` when the async process is complete. And never call `wait` on the main queue. You would want to use `notify`. Again though, do not use a dispatch group in this case.

You have two levels of async calls here. The first is in `loadImageForMetadata`. That needs to be refactored to provide a completion handler. The second is in `loadPhotosForSalonByPlaceId` which also needs to be refactored to provide a completion handler. You also need to redo how you use the dispatch group.

Here is your refactored `loadImageForMetadata`:

```
func loadImageForMetadata(photoMetadata: GMSPlacePhotoMetadata, completion: (Bool) -> Void) {
    var image = UIImage()
    GMSPlacesClient.shared().loadPlacePhoto(photoMetadata, callback: {
        (photo, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            // TODO: handle the error.
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(false)
        } else {
            image = photo!
            self.salonImages.append(image)
            completion(true)
        }
    })
}
```

Here is the refactored `loadPhotosForSalonByPlaceId` with a completion handler and the proper use of DispatchGroup:

```
func loadPhotosForSalonByPlaceId(placeID: String, completion: (Bool) -> Void) {
    var countToLimitToFiveImages = 0
    GMSPlacesClient.shared().lookUpPhotos(forPlaceID: placeID) { (photos, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            // TODO: handle the error.
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(false)
        } else {
            let group = DispatchGroup()

            for photoMetadata in (photos?.results)! {
                if countToLimitToFiveImages == 5 {
                    break;
                }
                group.enter()
                self.loadImageForMetadata(photoMetadata: photoMetadata) { (success) in
                     if success {
                         countToLimitToFiveImages += 1
                     }
                     group.leave()
                }
            }

            group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global()) {
                completion(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then update your usage:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    self.loadPhotosForSalonByPlaceId(placeID: poiItem.placeId) { (success) in
        if success {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let salonInfoViewController = self.addPullUpController() //show view controller

                salonInfoViewController.ImageCarouselView.images = self.salonImages
                salonInfoViewController.salonName.text = poiItem.name
                salonInfoViewController.salonAddress.text = poiItem.address
                salonInfoViewController.openAppointmentSlotArray = self.openAppointmentSlots
            }
        }
    }

    self.isSalonInfoViewPresented = true
    return isSalonInfoViewPresented
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. I have a question though. What if I want to use multiple async calls? Would DispatchGroup come in use then?

Comment: @SishirMohan Yes, a dispatch group is very useful when working with multiple async calls and you want to do something when all are finished.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have edited my question, could you take a look and see how I might be able to leverage Dispatch Group with the two async calls?

Comment: I have rewritten my answer based on your updated information about `loadImageForMetadata`.